# Why does augmented matrix allow for "distributive law" with matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am currently working with using augmented matrices to solve for systems of equations. This one question came up and I am confused why its true :

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are matrices having $n$ rows. Prove that $M(A|B)=(MA|MB)$ for any $m \times n$ matrix $M$

Does anyone have an explanation for why this is true?

Comment: Do you know summation notation? In particular, does the equation $(AB)_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} b_{k,j}$ make any sense to you?

Comment: Regardless, the generalization (which is in some sense easier to understand) is $A[b_1 \, b_2 \, b_3 \, \dots \, b_n]=[Ab_1 \, Ab_2 \, Ab_3 \, \dots \, Ab_n]$ (where the $b$'s are the columns of some matrix $B$.) Your problem is just this, with a bar shoved in the middle on each side. IMO if you do not understand this equation then you do not understand matrix-matrix multiplication (you might still understand matrix-vector multiplication).

Comment: @Ian I've always been hesitant to engage in the summation notation of matrix multiplication because it feels so messy. But now that you put it that way it makes sense because you are just finding the dot product of each horizontal term of $A$ with the columns of $B$. I feel like your equation is misworded, shouldn't it be more as $A[b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_n]=[A_{r1}b_1,A_{r1}b_2,A_{r1}b_3,\ldots,A_{r1}b_n]$ where $A_{r1}$ is the first row of $A$ since we are multiplying the first row to the nth column of B?

Comment: My equation is written correctly, it is saying that the $i$th column of $AB$ is given by multiplying $A$ with the $i$th column of $B$. What you wrote is the first row of $AB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are matrices over a field $F$ with the $n$ rows then we can think of $A:F^k\to F^n$ and $B:F^l\to F^n$ as linear maps. Here $k$ and $l$ are the number of columns of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Since these linear maps have the same target space we can build a new linear map $A|B:F^k\times F^l\to F^n$ using the formula $A|B(v,w)=Av+Bw$. There is a standard identification between $F^k\times F^l$ and $F^{k+l}$ and the augmented matrix $(A|B)$ is just the matrix for the linear map $A|B$ that is described above.

If $M$ is an $m\times n$ matrix then this can be regarded as a linear map from $F^n\to F^m$. Composing these we get $M(A|B):F^{k}\times F^l\to F^m$. But by examining the formula we find that

$$M(A|B)(v,w)=M(Av+Bw)=MA(v)+MB(w)=MA|MB(v,w)$$

What this means is that the linear maps $M(A|B)$ and $MA|MB$ are equal. Hence the augmented matrices $M(A|B)$ and $(MA|MB)$ are also equal.